# Error when opening downloads folder in Firefox

Tags: firefox

Every time I download anything and click on "open folder" in Firefox something else happens, instead of the required action a media player is open.

I just uploaded this video so you can see for yourselves what I'm talking about.

How can I troubleshoot this? What can be causing this? By the way, it's happening now with FF 57 but it also did with the previous version which I guess was 56.

I have no problems in Opera for this action. I'm on Linux Lite 3.6 x64.

Youtube [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SP4eY7htaSY) about the phenomenon. Clicking on the folder icon, a video play opens and not the folder.

Comment: Kindly check your default program for opening files.

Comment: Already did that...didn't work. Is there a way I can find why this is hapenning? I'll be happy to know just that. what procedure should I follow in order to isolate the possible cause(s)? I already googled for this but couldn't find anything. Thanks for your answer.